# Help with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Here is what I have so far:  I'm trying to get it so that when I click the calendar icon, the datepicker pops up also.  Just like when the text box is clicked.

Thanks for the help.

```
 <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14 /themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme /ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);

    $('#date').datepicker();

    });
          $(function()
                 {
                        $('.date-pick').datePicker({clickInput:true})
                });
      </script>

          </head>

        <body>

     <?php
        $da = $_POST['date'];

        $y= substr($da, 6, 4);
        $m= substr($da, 0, 2);
        $d= substr($da, 3, 2);

        print "IT IS " . $y . "-" . $m . "-" . $d;

     ?>
                <form name="oemail" method="post" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']    ?>">
                        <label for="date">The Date:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" readonly></input><img   class="date-pick" src="calendar.png"></img>
                        <input type="submit" id="sub"> </input>
                </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a stray capital `P`:

```
                    $('.date-pick').datepicker({clickInput:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the click() event of the image to the date picker.

Try this one:

```
$("img.date-pick").click(function(e) {
    $('#date').datepicker("show");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any javascript:

```
<label for="date"><img src='calendarPicture.png'/></label>
```

like in this http://jsfiddle.net/RYKTx/